# How to join rows from two MySQL tables based on related columns

Tags: mysql, database, join, relationship

I have an MySQL table called **PRODUCTS** and another table called **MEMBERS**. I am trying to use JOIN statement on INSERT query , so rows from each tables are combined based on related columns. For example rows in PRODUCTS table are joined with rows in MEMBER tables base don the related column which is (MEMBER NAME)

This is illustrated in a picture below:

[image]

Comment: Please publish your query. BTW that should be an insert not an update..AND I would suggest a junction table rather than duplicating product information in product. if indeed you need a table at all

Comment: Yes, you are right, it should be Insert rather than Update. INSERT INTO products (..,..,..) 
   select xxxx FROM products JOIN members;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two queries needed:

```
INSERT INTO products (p_code, s_name, c_prod, m_name)
SELECT t1.p_code, t1.s_name, t1.c_prod, t2.m_name
FROM products t1
CROSS JOIN members t2;

DELETE 
FROM products
WHERE m_name IS NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks. However, I used JOIN statement and it is working as expected

Comment: @KT2436 *I used JOIN statement and it is working as expected* JOIN is a clause, not a statement. And described action cannot be performed in one step - so sorry, but I don't believe.

Comment: Yes, that was a silly mistake. Indeed, it is a clause :) What do you mean? It can be performed in one step how ever there will be an extra row after creating records. So, if you mean adding  DELETE query then yes you are right

Comment: @KT2436 Creating new rows in my answer is one query. `INSERT .. SELECT`. DELETE needed for to remove initial rows which were used as a pattern and not needed after new rows creation.